# Vim's syntax color-highlighting is lost from command-line

Tags: vim

If I execute the following commands *from within* a `vim` session that's visiting a file of code, the resulting hardcopy is syntax highlighted *in color*:

```
:syntax on
:hardcopy >/path/to/hardcopy.ps
```

But if I try the same sequence of commands from the command line (Unix shell), the resulting hardcopy is *not color*-highlighted (I get just black text, sometimes bold, or underlined, etc., on a white background):

```
% vim -c ':syntax on' -c ':hardcopy >/path/to/hardcopy.ps' -c quit /path/to/original
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what may be at issue here is Vim's colorization is a kind of hack which is integrated with the display code. Note that, for instance, when you're jumping around in a large file, sometimes the coloring will be wrong, because Vim tries not to process the entire file in applying its hierarchical "region" pattern matches. Also, if your terminal doesn't support colors, then Vim will not print color or generate colorized HTML, even though those destinations have nothing to do with the terminal.

I once tried to turn Vim into a back end for doing on-the-fly syntax highlighting under CGIT, for viewing files in a GIT repository. I tried numerous hacks to try to get Vim to produce output in batch mode, but in the end I gave up.

But I stopped short of trying to use a utility like `expect`. Scripting Vim with `expect` is something that might work, provided you also lie to it, and tell it that it's talking to a color Xterm.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the environment variable `TERM` has an impact on the PS output colors used.

You can maybe try this:

```
TERM=xterm-256color vim '+hardcopy >out.ps' +q src_file
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
vim -R foo.yaml "+syntax on" "+syntax sync fromstart" "+ha>foo.yaml.ps" "+q"
```

The part you are missing is `"+syntax sync fromstart"`. Without that vim doesn't actually syntax-highlight any of the buffer.